# Mockito Mocked Class returns Null

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am using Mockito to mock a class in my JUnit test class as follows:

```
@Before
public void initialize(){
    DescribeHiveTable mockObj = Mockito.mock(DescribeHiveTable.class);
    String tableName = "clslog_assessments";
    String parentDirectoryPath ="src/test/resources/TEST18/RunFiles";
    String[] mockFeaturesArray1 = {"user_id","event_id"};
    ArrayList<String> mockFeaturesList1 = new ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList(mockFeaturesArray1));
    when(mockObj.describeTable(tableName, parentDirectoryPath)).thenReturn(mockFeaturesList1);
```

Then I have my Test method, which subsequently calls the `describeTable` method from within. 
I checked that the arguments: `tableName` and `parentDirectoryPath` when `describeTable` is being called are same as those I have defined in the initalize method.

However, I still get a null return value. I don't understand this behavior. Maybe I'm not using Mockito correctly?

**EDIT**

My Test method is something like:

```
@Test
public void testComplexFeaturesExistingRun() {
String[] args = {masterConfigPath, runFilesPath, rootDir};
DriverClass driver = new DriverClass();
driver.main(args);
}
```

So driver.main calls the describeTable method, whose behavior I'm trying to mock.

**EDIT 2**

My describe hive table class is :

```
public class DescribeHiveTable {

public ArrayList<String> describeTable(String tableName, String parentDirectoryPath){
    String hiveQuery = "'describe " + tableName + "';";
    String bashScriptFile = parentDirectoryPath + "/describeTable.sh";

    .
    .
    .
        final Process process = builder.start();
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
            String[] output = line.split("\t");
            columnList.add(output[0]);
       }
       return columnList;
```

This is how I'm calling describe table:

```
DescribeHiveTable describeTable;
describeTable = new DescribeHiveTable();
ArrayList<String> columnList = describeTable.describeTable(tableName, runFile.getParent());
```

Comment: I'm not seeing where your `mockObj`, declared as a local variable of `initialize()`, is leaving the scope of that method.  Is the problem that you're not publishing `mockObj` (in an instance field of the class) and therefore not using the mock object that you've so carefully constructed?

Comment: can you show us the code you are using in the test method ?

Comment: @DebojitSaikia, added my test method code

Comment: @Jeremy, I think you maybe right. What do you propose I should do?

Comment: I assume that the `DriverClass.main()` method has a `DescribeHiveTable` object inside it that you are trying to mock, is that correct? If so, you need to inject your mock into that class.

Comment: @Kyle, yes you're right. How do I inject a mock?

Comment: Is the DescribeHiveTable being injected with a framework like Spring using @Autowired or @Compenent? Can you show us how the DescribeHiveTable is being used? If it's a Spring inject class, you can use MockitoJUnitRunner and annotations to handle the config. If it's a class variable, you can use ReflectionTestUtils to inject the mock.

Comment: @Kyle, added my DescribeHiveTable class. It's just a simple Java class which writes and runs a shell script, but I'm testing on windows, hence the mocking

Comment: @Chaos i think you misunderstood, I'm curious how the class is being used in the code you want to test. I would like to see the declaration of the DescribeHiveTable variable in your DriverClass.main(), is it a variable being initialized locally with `new` or is it a class variable inject by spring with something like `@Component` or `@Resource`

Comment: @Kyle, added that to the question, its initialized with new...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37764/discussion-between-kyle-and-chaos)

Comment: @Chaos, please read this Mockito wiki page https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation - it has the information that you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to use Mockito is

```
private DescribeHiveTable mockObj; // must be accessible to Test methods

@Before
public void initialize(){
    this.mockObj = Mockito.mock(DescribeHiveTable.class);
    <etc>
}

@Test
public void testComplexFeaturesExistingRun() {
    /* test the objects that are set up to use this.mockObj,
       and not the usual type of DescribeHiveTable */
}
```

Note that

```
describeTable = new DescribeHiveTable();
```

means that you're using a new, unmocked, `DescribeHiveTable`, not the mocked `mockObj`.

But it looks like you don't have control over the `DescribeHiveTable` instance used by the `DriverClass`?  If that's the case then either

- Mockito isn't going to help you -- or you at least have to mock the `DriverClass` too; or
- you have to use reflection to replace the `describeTable` in `DriverClass` with `mockObj`.

Comment: Appears reflection is definitely going to be the answer here. Here's the code to use Reflection to set the variable equal to your Mock object: `DriverClass driverClass = new DriverClass(); Class class = driverClass.getClass(); Field field = class.getDeclaredField("describeTable"); field.setAccessible(true); field.set(driverClass, mockedDriverClass);`

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the `DriverClass` with a mock of `DescribeHiveTable`(provided `DescribeHiveTable` is an instance variable of `DriverClass`) as below:

```
public class TestClass{

@Mock
DescribeHiveTable mockObj;
// This will create a new instance of DriverClass with a mock of DescribeHiveTable
@InjectMocks
DriverClass driver;

@Before
    public void init() {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        tableName = "clslog_assessments";
        parentDirectoryPath = "src/test/resources/TEST18/RunFiles";
        mockFeaturesArray1 = new String[] { "user_id", "event_id" };
        mockFeaturesList1 = new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList(mockFeaturesArray1));
        when(mockObj.describeTable(tableName, parentDirectoryPath)).thenReturn(
                mockFeaturesList1);
}

@Test
public void test() {
    // when(methodCall)
    assertEquals(mockFeaturesList1, driver.main());
}

}
```